# Какой тип коллеции без возможности добавления выбрать для один-ко-многим?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Во всех примерах, что я вижу в интернете используется `ICollection`, но он позволяет добавлять элементы в коллекцию.

Какой следует выбрать тип, если я **не** хочу, чтобы был доступен `Add`, но при этом работало "один-ко-многим" и ленивая загрузка?

Я думал использовать `IEnumerable`, но он вроде загружает всю коллецию и я лишаюсь lazy load.

Стоит ли тогда использовать `IQueryble`?

Comment: А зачем нужно, такое странное ограничение: "...я не хочу, чтобы был доступен Add.."? Если вы хотите работать с базой в режиме readonly, то не проще ли это сделать на уровне СУБД, т.е. ограничить в правах аккаунт на самом сервере СУБД?

Comment: @Bulson, ну.. я подумал, что будет правильно, если коллекция не позволяет добавлять/удалять, то об этом кричал уже IntelliSense и компилятор, а оно не всплывало при обращении в БД.

Comment: Начиная с .Net Framework 4.5 появилась `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` можете попробовать поработать с ней. Правда мне кажется, что проще всего настроить права доступа для аккаунта под которым работает ваша программа с СУБД.

Comment: Используя `IEnumerable` вы вовсе не лишаетесь lazy loading. И да, использование `IEnumerable` подходит для вашего случая. И как выше посоветовали, `ReadOnly*`-коллекции тоже годятся (они добавляют некоторые свойства, могущие оказаться полезными: например, `Count`, доступ по индексу).

Comment: Если у вас связь один-ко-многим, то добавить продукт к заказу можно не только как `order.Products.Add(product)`, но и как `product.Order = order`

Comment: И да, для нормальной работы навигационных свойств требуется как минимум `ICollection`, вроде (пока не нашел подтверждения в документации)